# How can I improve this code since it involves thousands of rows and many formulas to update?

Tags: excel, vba

The code below involves over 20,000 rows and 6 columns of formulas which need to be updated, how can I simplify it to reduce time?

```
With Sheets("CDGL")
Sheets("Rec").Range("B6").Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row - 1, 3).Value = Sheets("Duplicate Check").Range("A1:C" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value
Sheets("Rec").Range("E6").Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row - 1, 4).Value = Sheets("Duplicate Check").Range("D1:G" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value
Sheets("Rec").Range("I6").Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row - 1, 1).Value = Sheets("Duplicate Check").Range("H1:H" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value
End With
```

Comment: Why do you have `With Sheets("CDGL")` but then use the `Range` from "REC", but using the cells on CDGL?  You are aware of that, yes?

Comment: @BruceWayne, yes I do will that change the time?

Answer (score 0):

Your `With` statement looks odd - but it's not necessarily wrong..  Do you know how these work, and why I'm concerned with how it's written? If so, then ignore this. If you aren't sure how to use `With`, or why I'm concerned with how you have it written, let me know as the below code is almost 100% guaranteed not to do what you expect.

```
Sub t()
Dim cdglWS As Worksheet
Dim recWS As Worksheet
Dim dupWS As Worksheet

Set cdglWS = Sheets("CDGL")
Set recWS = Sheets("Rec")
Set dupWS = Sheets("Duplicate Check")

With recWS
    .Range("B6").Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row - 1, 3).Value = dupWS.Range("A1:C" & dupWS.Cells(dupWS.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value
    .Range("E6").Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row - 1, 4).Value = dupWS.Range("D1:G" & dupWS.Cells(dupWS.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value
    .Range("I6").Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row - 1, 1).Value = dupWS.Range("H1:H" & dupWS.Cells(dupWS.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value
End With

End Sub
```

What is your goal with the macro? As you have it, you are going to take a cell's value from your `Duplicate Check` sheet, then put that value in a cell in your `Rec` worksheet.

Which cell that is depends on the data you have in your `CDGL` sheet. It's using the last row from `CDGL` to decide which cell in `Rec` to place the value from `Duplicate Check`.  (at least I think so).  Is that your intention?

In your OP, it would help if you edited with a short explanation of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi @BruceWayne. I am trying to do exactly what you stated and take one value from Duplicate Check and place it into the range of the Rec WS...however there are thousands of rows and many formulas which make the process extremely long..I am trying to figure out a way to reduce that time

Comment: @Hags - What's the `CDGL` sheet doing? Is that where you want the data to go? Or just use that with to get your rows and such.  Do you know what I'm getting at?

Comment: the CDGL sheet has no impact and I should change that, the sheet data specifically correlates Rec and Duplicate Check, my apologies

Comment: @Hags - I've updated the code. Now, I think it'll do what you're looking for. Check that the ranges are being pulled correctly, I wasn't sure if you wanted `recWS` to be the "main sheet" or not, so switch those as necessary.

Comment: If I want to have the formulas update at the end how would I include that? @BruceWayne

Comment: @Hags - If I understand you, just change the `.Value` to `.Formula`.